# Почему в фреймворках и библиотеках PHP цепочка вызовов начинается со статичного метода?

Tags: php, yii2, ооп, fluent-interface

Часто видел в фреймворках (таких как Yii2) цепочки вызовов вроде
`Table::find()->select()->where(..)->all()`
Погуглив, понял, что это называется текучим интерфейсом, когда метод возвращает $this, чтобы в контексте объекта продолжать использовать методы объекта, но почему первый вызов обычно всегда идет со static метода, который в итоге возвращает новый экземпляр самого себя (new static()) или другого объекта.
Почему не делают просто?

```
(new Table())->find()->select()->where(..)->all();
```

Хотя подразумеваю, что смущает оборачивание экземпляра в скобки, но все же?

Comment: сдается мне что ваши "обычно всегда" с практикой то не особо стыкуются, увидели в одном из фреймворков, и почему-то обобщили. . Вопрос в том, нужен вам экземпляр или нет, если не нужен, то зачем его и создавать. Тут ведь `find()` возвращает какой-нибудь query builder, то есть таблица сама по себе не требуется, следовательно зачем тратить  ресурсы на то, что не надо?

Comment: флюент апи тот собственно тоже не при делах. Вопрос сугубо в использовании статических методов, а что там дальше вызывать к делу не относится.

Comment: Иногда это используется если объект реализован как синглтон

Comment: Это пример использования в ООП техники *utility-классов*, для предоставления доступа к популярным процедурам из разных участков кода. Существует мнение, что это антипаттерн.

Comment: Потому что вместо  `new Table()` может быть что-то вроде `new Table($db, $log, $otherThing ...)`, которые также нужно создавать (иногда в единственном экземпляре, и у них тоже могут быть зависимости). А если сигнатура (конструктор) поменяется, то вам придётся переписывать уйму кода, что вообще очень плохо.